# Не работает x-webkit-speech

Tags: html5, голосовой-поиск

Мне нужно реализовать голосовой поиск на сайте, вставил в `input` атрибут `x-webkit-speech`, однако никакого микрофончика в `input type="text"` нету.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```js
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');

if (document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech === undefined) {
  msg.innerHTML = "x-webkit-speech is <strong>not supported</strong> in your browser.";
} else {
  msg.innerHTML = "x-webkit-speech is <strong>supported</strong> in your browser.";
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 640px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}
input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #BABABA;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.8em;
  background: #69c773;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #498b50;
  color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Speech Input Demo / Tester</h1>

  <p id="msg"></p>

  <label for="text">Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="text" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="number">Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="url">URL</label>
  <input type="url" id="url" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="tel">Telephone</label>
  <input type="tel" id="tel" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="date">Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="date" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="datetime">Date and Time</label>
  <input type="datetime" id="datetime" x-webkit-speech>

  <label for="month">Month</label>
  <input type="month" id="month" x-webkit-speech>

</div>
```

[Ссылка на Codepen](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/wbpqu).

Или такого атрибута больше не существует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот атрибут был удален из Chrome из-за уязвимости в коде, начиная с версии v36:
[Disabling Chrome’s x-webkit-speech vulnerability](https://blogs.janestreet.com/disabling-chromes-x-webkit-speech-vulnerability/)

Подробнее об уязвимости здесь:
[Eavesdrop on the user speech - abusing the old speech API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360448) — [Issue]
[To Listen Without Consent – Abusing the HTML5 Speech](https://blog.guya.net/2014/04/07/to-listen-without-consent-abusing-the-html5-speech/) — [Статья с пояснениями]

---

Однако существует альтернатива в виде расширения [speech-input](https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input).

К сожалению, поддержка браузерами все равно [низкая](http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition).